# Issue in regular expression in Perl with =~

Tags: regex

Please help me with this program. 
Target is to change the content of a file from GENFlag=NO to GENFlag=YES

I have written a piece of code to match and then print to the outputfile but here even though it is not matching it is printing into the file.  Please find the code below:

```
if($x =~ /$z/)
{ 
    $flag = "yes";
    $x =~ s/GenFlag=.*/GenFlag=YES/;
    print OUTPUT "$x";
    print OUTPUT "\n";
    #print " printed YES \n";
    last;
}
```

The complete code is as follows:

```
%PmNodes = (
    GGSN => ["ggsnGenFlag","ggsnMpgGenFlag","ggsnPgwGenFlag","ggsnSgwGenFlag","epgMbmSgwGenFlag","ggsnNodeGenFlag",],
    CNAXE => [ "mscApgGenFlag" ,"mscIogGenFlag","mscBcGenFlag", "hlrApgGenFlag" , "hlrIogGenFlag" ],
    SGSN => ["enable3gppGenFlag" ,"ebssSgsnGenFlag" , "sgsnGenFlag" , "sgsnMmeGenFlag"],
    MGW => ["mgwGenFlag"],
    IMSMGW =>["imsGenFlag"],
    SASN => ["sasnGenFlag","sasnSaraGenFlag"],
    SAPC => ["sapcGenFlag"],
    IMSGW_SBG => ["sbgGenFlag"],
    IMS =>["imsWuigmGenFlag" ,"imsGenFlag","imsMGenFlag"],
    HSS =>["hssGenFlag"],
    ERBS =>["wranLteGenFlag" , "erbsg2GenFlag"],
    TDRNC => ["tdRNCGenFlag"],
    RAN => ["ebawRncGenFlag" , "RncGenFlag"],
    BSS => ["bscApgGenFlag" , "bscIogGenFlag"],
    RBS => ["wranRBSGenFlag"],
    STN => ["Tcu03GenFlag", "stnPicoGenFlag" , "stnSiuGenFlag" , "stnTcuGenFlag" ],                
    REDB => ["mlpppGenFlag"],
    CPG => ["cpgGenFlag"],
    IPPROBE => ["twampGenFlag"],
    TDRBS => ["tdRBSGenFlag"],                
    PRBS_ERBS => ["wranLteGenFlag"],
    PRBS_RBS => ["PRBSGenFlag"],
    DCE => ["dscGenFlag"],
    EPDG => ["epdgGenFlag"],
    );



foreach my $y (@array)
{
    @inputarray = GetPmvalues($y);
    print " array input :: @inputarray \n";
    foreach my $z (@inputarray)
    {               
        $flag = "no";
        print " line :: $x \t value :: $z \n";
        next if($z eq "");
        if($x =~ /$z/)
        { 
            $flag = "yes";
            $x =~ s/GenFlag=.*/GenFlag=YES/;
            print OUTPUT "$x";
            print OUTPUT "\n";
            #print " printed YES \n";
            last;
        }           
    }           
}
if ( $flag eq "no")
{
    print OUTPUT "$x";
    print OUTPUT "\n";
        print " printed NO \n";
    last;
}
}
```

Comment: a small part of code is here

Comment: Why not `$x =~ s/GenFlag=NO/GenFlag=YES/;`.. if you just want to change NO to YES